# Laravel White Screen - Possible Mcrypt issue?

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel

I have a laravel 4 app that is working great locally. When I deploy to an ubuntu server, I get nothing but a white screen.

- Server serves up other PHP files normally. Just the app gives me a white screen.
- When I try and install a fresh laravel instance on the server using composer, I get an error that mcrypt is required.
- If I do phpinfo(), it shows that mcrypt is enabled.
- I have already tried chmodding the application directory to give it rw permissions (as seen in another SO white screen question) Seems to have had no results.

Any other advice to look into?

Comment: Please post the contents at the bottom of `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: Have you restarted your web server after installing mcrypt?

Comment: Result from Log:

PHP Fatal Error: Class 'Patchwork\\Utf8\\Bootup' not found in /var/www/html/appname/appfolder/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 46

Comment: Yes I have restarted apache after installing mcrypt.

Comment: Run `composer update --no-scripts`

Comment: No problem, since it solved your problem I will put it in an answer and you can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `composer update --no-scripts` and that will do the trick.

Comment: @NoahMatisoff Probably a good idea to alliterate WHY this worked as well.

Comment: Because it needed to be updated and without the `--no-scripts` flag it would've thrown the same error.